# CCLabelBMFont alignment not working

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocos2d-iphone

I'm creating a bitmap font label like so:

```
CCLabelBMFont *label = [CCLabelBMFont labelWithString:@"Hello" fntFile:@"HeaderFont.fnt" width:300 alignment:kCCTextAlignmentLeft];
```

Then I'm poisitioning it at:

```
label.position =  ccp(0, size.height-100);
```

So I'm thinking the label should be start drawing from the left-most side of the screen (0), and a little below the top (size.height-100), but when the label draws, it's appearing offset to the left, like it's drawing on the X axis at -200 or something. Its as thought the alignment just isn't working at all.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

//x-axis Left alignment : y-center

```
label.anchorPoint = ccp(0.0f,0.5f);
label.position = startCharPos;
```

//x-axis Right alignment : y-center

```
label.anchorPoint = ccp(1.0f,0.5f);
label.position = startCharPos;
```

I guess u want to align left-top. So try this

```
label.anchorPoint = ccp(0.0f,1.0f);
label.position = startCharPos;
```

Comment: Thanks! I managed to debug all the possible settings when I turned on the debug bounding boxes in ccConfig.h.